# How can i change UISearchBar placeholder alignment to right ? IOS Swift IOS version > 9.3

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, ios10.3

I have done it as

```
let searchTextField: UITextField? = (searchBar.value(forKey: "_searchField") as? UITextField)
searchTextField.textAlignment = .right
```

its working fine on `IOS version <= 9.3` but problem in `IOS version > 9.3`

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any solutions  ?

Comment: still no solution

Comment: I added some white spaces in my placeholder text , it's an ugly one but it works...

Comment: u can create ur own search bar instead of doing this :)